# Unable to execute measure stored in Analysis Services/Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net

I'm trying to see if I can write tests in C# that will validate the measures in a model; to do I need to execute the measure and compare the result with an implementation in C# that should be the same.

I've set up a basic Power BI-report containing a couple of tables and measures. One of the measures is a simple `count('fact_data'[Item])`, and works as expected when I'm looking at it in the report.

When connecting to the model via ADOMD.NET I'm able to extract the measure expression programmatically, but when I try to run it via the [AdomdDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomddataadapter.-ctor?view=analysisservices-dotnet#Microsoft_AnalysisServices_AdomdClient_AdomdDataAdapter__ctor_System_String_System_String_) all I get is

```
AdomdErrorResponseException: Query (1, 18) The syntax for '[Item]' is incorrect. (COUNT('fact_data'[Item])).
```

Other and more basic queries where I simply return table contents work without problem.
No matter what I try I cannot get this to execute; if I rename the column or table to something that doesn't exist, I get an error about this so it would seem that the query is executed, but that something is either wrong or missing in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to do this via ExecuteScalar(), but wrapping the DAX in a ROW() seems to work for stored measures.